# How to maintain the page state when browser back button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, back-button

I have a page with Client side paggination and Filtration. The page lists around 200-300 prouducts.
The page contains some filters like Category,Manufacturer and Weight. 
Clicking upon any of the page number or filter, I am manupulating the page content on client side using Jquery.

Everything is working fine till this step. Now there is a usecase where I am facing problem.

1. Lets say a user comes to our product listing page and click on some of the filters and gets a list of products.
2. Now he clicks on a particular product , which redirects him to the product page to view the details of the product.
3. But now when the user clicks on the back button , the user gets the page with the intial state without any filter selected.

Is there any way user will get the page with the filters previously selected on clicking the back button?

Comment: store the state in a service, check for state when controller intitializes

Comment: You are talking about breadcrumbs which can be done in backend part of application, but also u can use localStorage. Provide html of your filters for further help.

Comment: what do you mean by "service" in this context? I would store the settings in cookies

Answer (score 3):

You can use some of the following to store data across multiple pages.

1. Store data in [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie).
2. Store data in [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).
3. Store data in the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) on the server.
4. Make the data part of your URL (use [hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hash) or [query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.searchParams) for the filter parameters). Note that changing query string causes page reload.

If using cookies, local storage, or hash, you'll need to add JavaScript code to your page that loads and applies the stored data on page load.

Comment: Lets say clicking upon a particular filter(Checkbox) I will add that value to the page url (Ex: page.cfm?categoryid=4,5) , and now I need to check these url variable on document.ready and trigger those filters through jquery? Am i correct?

Comment: Yep. But I'll move this option to the bottom of the list, because it causes page reload on each filter selection. If your application is purely client-based, I'd suggest using cookies or local storage.

Comment: Is it not possible to append filters to the url on filter selection with out refreshing the page.

Comment: It actually is. You'd just have to use the `hash` portion of the URL, not the query string.

Comment: My filtration is completely Client side . I do not need to make any ajax call on selecting a filter. I am just hiding the products that does not match filter criteria.Let say if i will store the filter value in cookie on selecting the filter ,On clicking back button I need to check those cookies on document.ready and manually trigger the filters ? Am I going in correct direction/?

Comment: You are. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways to do this:

1. If you are dealing with html5 history and a single-page application, then you are not reloading the page. But based on your question, I assume this is not what you are dealing with.
2. Store something in the URL. For an example of this, look at the filters on TotalHockey, e.g. http://www.totalhockey.com/Search.aspx?category_2=Sticks%2fComposite%20Sticks&chan_id=1&div_main_desc=Intermediate&category_1=Sticks so when you go backwards, the URL contains the entire state.
3. Use localstorage, if you have a browser that supports it.
4. use cookies with the $.cookie API
5. Store it on the session in the server.

Comment: @hon2a you and I must have crossed wires! Good to validate! I will upvote yours too!

Comment: Lets say clicking upon a particular filter(Checkbox) I will add that value to the page url (Ex: page.cfm?categoryid=4,5) , and now I need to check these url variable on document.ready and trigger those filters through jquery? Am i correct? Can it be done using jquery only or I need to use History API. I have no knowledge on history API.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the Search Filter Data in session just after submitting on the filter input and on each ajax request (Loading your product listing), you can check the search filter inputs stored in the session and show the data according to them. If search session is empty then show whole listing.

You can also store the full ajax request URL (if GET method is used) in the session after searching the record and hit that particular URL again after coming back from product detail page.